# Node.js Automate Login and Upload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a node.js script that automatically creates a group of files and then zips them ready for being uploaded on a site. I'm trying to add one extra piece of functionality to the script that will log into the site and upload the file itself.

I've done some reading around and found a lot about headless browsers but not sure if that's the right path to go down as they seem to rely on other applications like chromium and they're focused on testing sites.

Does anyone know where I should start looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my current project I am using the following library from Google, [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). I personally found it to be very easy to use, and it even provides access to the dev protocol that Google Chrome has.

> I've done some reading around and found a lot about headless browsers but not sure if that's the right path to go down as they seem to rely on other applications like chromium and they're focused on testing sites.

Yes, they are often used for testing, to assure that the correct things are rendered on screen etc. However, in many scenarios, like yours, the use of a headless browser to interact with a website is totally legit in a non-testing scenario.

Comment: Still using puppeteer today and it has made so many tasks so much easier for me. I love it so much. Thanks again for this answer.